# toggle value is same every where in ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm new to Ionic. I want to update the toggle value as status (activated and deactivated) in `Array1` and `Array2`. When I update the status in `Array1` it also updates in `Array2`. I only want to update one status.

I'm using Ionic 4 and Angular7

```
second.page.ts
ionViewWillEnter(i){
    let task = this.activeRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('i'); //get value from array with the help of router
    this.tasks = this.dataService.getTask();

    let updatedToggleStatus = this.dataService.getStatus();

    if(updatedToggleStatus == false){
      this.deactive = false;
    }
    else if(updatedToggleStatus == true){
      this.deactive = true;
    }
  }

statusActive(){
    var toggleStatus = this.deactive;
    let i = this.activeRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('i');
    this.tasks = this.dataService.getTask();
    this.dataService.statusToggle(toggleStatus,i);
  }

data.service.ts

statusToggle(toggleStatus,i){ 
    if(toggleStatus == false){
      this.togStatus = toggleStatus;
      console.log('deactivated');
      }
    else if(toggleStatus == true){
      this.togStatus = toggleStatus;
      console.log('activated');
      console.log(this.togStatus,'tog')
    }
  }

  getStatus(){
    // console.log(i)
    return this.togStatus;      
  }
```

I just want to update one array status but both array status's are updating with one click on toggle

Answer (score 0):

**In the template code:**

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="toggle01" (ionChange)="toggleTwo()"></ion-toggle>
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="toggle02" (ionChange)="toggleOne()"></ion-toggle>
```

**In the Component code declare two booleans and two funtions like this:**

```
toggle01: boolean = true;
toggle02: boolean = false;
```

.......

```
toggleOne() {
  this.toggle01 = !this.toggle02;
}

toggleTwo() {
  this.toggle02 = !this.toggle01;
}
```

**and this should work pretty good!**

Comment: i m only using one toggle. In firstpage i have list of arrays like tasks=[{task1Name,task1Status}, {task2Name,task2Status}]

Comment: routing details from first to second with the help of router.

Comment: and on second page I an showing the details of array1 and there i am having toggle to change the status

Comment: you can use one toggle

Comment: can pass value throgh navigation